# Download Large Image From Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to download Large image from facebbok. i am able to download normal size image throw this code ::

```
            try{
                   phtoID.clear();
            response = facebook.request(HelperActivity.wallAlbumID
                    + "/photos");
            JSONObject json = null;
            json = Util.parseJson(response);
            JSONArray photos = null;
            photos = json.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject a = null;
                a = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                String url = a.getString("picture");
                Log.d("URL",url);
                URL imageURL = new URL(url);
                Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
                phtoID.add(mIcon1);
            }
```

Help !!

Comment: i am not getting error.. only want to download large size images..

Answer (score 0):

You actually have the largest photo already. Instead of `picture`, get `images[0].source` which should be the largest version of the picture. Each `images` element also has a `width` and `height` property  that returns the size of the photo as an integer in px.

The [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a great tool to see what an API endpoint returns.